# Adding a new event parameter key to an existing query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to add in an events params.key of "sr_posting_id" to my query below, but the value itself is in the event_params.value.int_value column where everything else is under event_params.value.string_value (see screenshot for reference). How do I add this event parameter into my query and get the data?

[image: Screenshot of initial data]

```
SELECT 
  event_name, 
  event_date, 
  traffic_source.medium, 
  traffic_source.name, 
  traffic_source.source, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(traffic_source.medium, traffic_source.source)) AS event_count
FROM 
  `nth-glider-369017.analytics_316822874.events_*`, 
  UNNEST(event_params) AS param
WHERE 
  event_name IN ("sr_job_application_started", "sr_job_application_continued", "sr_job_completed_application")
  AND param.key IN ("term", "campaign", "source", "medium", "engaged_session_count", "sr_posting_id")
  AND param.key = "sr_posting_id"
  AND event_params.value.int_value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
  event_name, 
  event_date, 
  traffic_source.medium, 
  traffic_source.name, 
  traffic_source.source;
```

I've tried adding in sr_posting_id to the param.key section, but got this error: Cannot access field value on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>>> at [15:20]